# Jobs not running in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, cypress

I have created projects on Azure Devops. I have also created pipelines. But I am getting notification telling that "**Pipelines in your region may be impacted by a live site incident, resulting in possible pipeline delays.**" and when I click on Job, then it gives message "**This agent request is not running because you have reached the maximum number of requests that can run for parallelism type 'Microsoft-Hosted Public'. Current position in queue: 1**"

I have also tried setting my project to public and private but didn't work. I am searching for the solution but didn't find any useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new organisation?  Microsoft no longer automatically provides free hosted agents.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-184-update#changes-to-azure-pipelines-free-grants

If you navigate to Parallel Jobs in the project settings, how many jobs does it show available.